# How to set Retention Policy to 1 week in InfluxDb Processor in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, influxdb

I am consuming data from Kafka and pushing it to InfluxDb. Following is my flow:

ConsumeKafka_2_0 -> PutInfluxDatabaseRecord

Currently, my Retention policy is set to 'autogen', how can I change this setting to **1 week** retention period?  I did try '7d' and '1week' in the retention policy field in the processor but didn't work. I am using the influx version 1.7.9

What Nifi Expression Language to give in the processor? Any help is much appreciated. I am new to InfluxDatabase

[image]

Thanks In advance!